# Hosted service doesn't get data from axapta

Tags: c#, json, wcf, axapta, business-connector

I created a WCF-service, which connect with Axapta, gets data from it and serializes data to JSON-string. I use "Business Connector" for this.

When I test WCF in "Page Inspector", on localhost, the service works fine. But when I hosted it on IIS, the service stopped getting data from Axapta.

And my Json string becomes empty: `{"nomekl":[]}` (nomekl is my class for axapta's data).

In localhost, this json contains data:

```
{"nomekl":
    [
        {"group_num":"КА470105010404","name":"Part1"},
        {"group_num":"КА470105010405","name":"Part2"},
        {"group_num":"КА470105010406"... and etc
```

I'm setting business connector, but it still doesn't work in hosted WCF. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: The WCF in "Page Inspector" on localhost is presumably running under your user account?  What is the IIS account (application pool?) run as?  Can you run it to impersonate your own user account? This is just for test purposes as you will change your password periodically.

Comment: Check your [IIS logs](https://portal.smartertools.com/kb/a2487/where-are-my-iis-log-files-stored.aspx) and update your post with any relevant messages.